# Effective Hamiltonian of the Hubbard model

Tags: hamiltonian, effective-field-theory

In Girvin and Yang's appendix that deals with effective Hamiltonian (p. 677) they discuss the example of a two sites Hubbard model of spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ fermions.

The Hamiltonian is

$$
H = T + V \\
T = -t \sum_\sigma (c^\dagger_{1\sigma}c_{2\sigma} + c^\dagger_{2\sigma}c_{1\sigma}) \\ 
V = U\sum_{j=1}^2 n_{j\uparrow}n_{j\downarrow}
$$

where $\sigma \in \{\uparrow, \downarrow \}$, and $U \gg |t|$. The low-energy states are the state with no occupancy at all, and those with only a single fermion at each sites. The high energy states are those with double occupancy (in one site or both).

The process of finding the low-energy effective Hamiltonian is described. It is done by a unitary diagonalization with a unitary matrix $W=e^S$ that ends up giving a new Hamiltonian -

$$
\tilde{H}= W^\dagger H W
$$

The Hamiltonian annihilates the high energy spectrum of $H$.

The operator $S$ is defined by noting that $T$ can be written as a some of operators with distinct action on the state space:

$$
T = T_0 + T_+ + T_-
$$
Where, it is said that "T_m  corresponds to hops that change the number of doubly occupied sites by $m$" (here $m= 0,\pm 1$). Then $S= \frac{1}{U}(T_+ - T_-)$.

What bothers me here is that $T_0, T_+,T_-$ do not seem to be well defined. For any of the terms in $T$ as listed above it is possible to find low-energy states where these terms act as if they should be part of any one of $T_0, T_+, T_-$.

For example consider $c = c^\dagger_{1\uparrow}c_{2\uparrow}$:

$$ 
c |\downarrow_1,\uparrow_2 \rangle = |\downarrow_1\uparrow_1 \rangle \\
c=|\downarrow_2\uparrow_2 \rangle = |\uparrow_1,\downarrow_2 \rangle \\
c |\uparrow_2 \rangle = |\uparrow_1 \rangle
$$

In the first row $c$ increases the number of doubly occupied sites, in the second row that number is decreased and in the last row it is unchanged.

In the end of the discussion the reader is instructed to repeat the derivation for spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ boson, there it is said that the energy cost for a double occupation of the same spin in the same site is $U$. How is that evident from the Hamiltonian?

I would also to gain an intuition into the general process diagonalization. It seems $e^{\lambda S}$ seems to be a useful guess, with the next step guessing a good valued for $\lambda$. In the above discussion it is $\lambda = \frac{1}{U}$. In another example discussed earlier in that section by Girvin and yang this choice also seems to work. Where do all these "guesses" come from? Can we think of the unitary $e^S$ as some time evolution in an interaction picture? Is there a simple way to see what operators will come up when calculating the effective Hamiltonian, or some way (maybe combinatoric) to see what values will the coefficients assume?

Comment: An operator that is the product of a creation and annihilation operator is not a member of any of the T, as you've just discovered. Rather, it's a linear combination of operators belonging to different T operators. You might find it challenging to write the T operators in second quantized notation, but you'll find if much easier to write their action explicitly in the first quantization using the occupation number basis.

Comment: @JahanClaes You mean writing $T_0$ as sum of terms like for example $|\uparrow_1\downarrow_1\rangle\langle\uparrow_1\downarrow_1|, \;  |\uparrow_2\downarrow_2\rangle\langle\uparrow_1\downarrow_1| , \;  |\downarrow_1\downarrow_2\rangle\langle\uparrow_1\uparrow_2|$, etc? How would you write that in second quantization?

Comment: This is a [Schrieffer-Wolff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schrieffer%E2%80%93Wolff_transformation) transformation.

Comment: This is the right idea, although $T_0$ has to involve exactly one hop, so none of the terms you wrote are part of $T_0$. $T_O$ only acts on singly occupied basis elements. And I don't think you can write this operator in second quantized notation.

Comment: @JahanClaes Than how do you write these operators? And how come they can be meaningfully used together with a second-quantized Hamiltonian?

Comment: Or what is the fundamental reason second quantization can't be used to describe operators like $T_0,\; T_\pm$?